# Running C++11 programs

Tags: c++, c++11

I installed gcc4.8 in scientific linux using:

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-devtoolset.repo http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo
yum install devtoolset-2

gcc --version gives me: gcc4.8
```

Now my problem is when I now run C++11 programs on gcc (using netbeans IDE) I get the error:

```
/home/topK/CppApplication_7/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapplication_7: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.17' not found (required by /home/topK/CppApplication_7/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapplication_7)
/home/topK/CppApplication_7/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapplication_7: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by /home/topK/CppApplication_7/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapplication_7)
/home/topK/CppApplication_7/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapplication_7: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /home/topK/CppApplication_7/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapplication_7)
```

Can someone please help me as to how can I get rid of this error.

EDIT: locate libstdc++
OUTPUT:

```
/usr/lib/libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so
/usr/lib/libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libstdc++.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/32/libstdc++.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/32/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5.0.7
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7/ChangeLog-1998.bz2
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7/ChangeLog-1999.bz2
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7/ChangeLog-2000.bz2
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7/ChangeLog-2001.bz2
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7/ChangeLog-2002.bz2
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7/ChangeLog-2003.bz2
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7/ChangeLog-2004.bz2
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7/ChangeLog-2005.bz2
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7/ChangeLog-2006.bz2
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7/ChangeLog-2007.bz2
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7/ChangeLog.bz2
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7/ChangeLog~.bz2
/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-devel-4.4.7/README
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13-gdb.py
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13-gdb.pyc
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13-gdb.pyo
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13-gdb.py
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13-gdb.pyc
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13-gdb.pyo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/32df1c3f56009c7df737dd4bfbd327bb0aef8d6e-compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6-i686
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/a34683059a40d1d3401aab2723d7b68c8e1cbe15-compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6-x86_64
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/32df1c3f56009c7df737dd4bfbd327bb0aef8d6e-compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6-i686/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/32df1c3f56009c7df737dd4bfbd327bb0aef8d6e-compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6-i686/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/32df1c3f56009c7df737dd4bfbd327bb0aef8d6e-compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6-i686/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/32df1c3f56009c7df737dd4bfbd327bb0aef8d6e-compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6-i686/from_repo_revision
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/32df1c3f56009c7df737dd4bfbd327bb0aef8d6e-compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6-i686/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/32df1c3f56009c7df737dd4bfbd327bb0aef8d6e-compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6-i686/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/32df1c3f56009c7df737dd4bfbd327bb0aef8d6e-compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6-i686/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/32df1c3f56009c7df737dd4bfbd327bb0aef8d6e-compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6-i686/releasever
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/a34683059a40d1d3401aab2723d7b68c8e1cbe15-compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6-x86_64/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/a34683059a40d1d3401aab2723d7b68c8e1cbe15-compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6-x86_64/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/a34683059a40d1d3401aab2723d7b68c8e1cbe15-compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6-x86_64/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/a34683059a40d1d3401aab2723d7b68c8e1cbe15-compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6-x86_64/from_repo_revision
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/a34683059a40d1d3401aab2723d7b68c8e1cbe15-compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/a34683059a40d1d3401aab2723d7b68c8e1cbe15-compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6-x86_64/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/a34683059a40d1d3401aab2723d7b68c8e1cbe15-compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6-x86_64/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/c/a34683059a40d1d3401aab2723d7b68c8e1cbe15-compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6-x86_64/releasever
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/cd38d7a96e461667eb9113f1fddb8a1e43d94178-libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/d804bf01331824c1a148301bc5102dd7276e5136-libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/cd38d7a96e461667eb9113f1fddb8a1e43d94178-libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/changed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/cd38d7a96e461667eb9113f1fddb8a1e43d94178-libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/cd38d7a96e461667eb9113f1fddb8a1e43d94178-libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/cd38d7a96e461667eb9113f1fddb8a1e43d94178-libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/command_line
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/cd38d7a96e461667eb9113f1fddb8a1e43d94178-libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/cd38d7a96e461667eb9113f1fddb8a1e43d94178-libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/from_repo_revision
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/cd38d7a96e461667eb9113f1fddb8a1e43d94178-libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/cd38d7a96e461667eb9113f1fddb8a1e43d94178-libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/cd38d7a96e461667eb9113f1fddb8a1e43d94178-libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/cd38d7a96e461667eb9113f1fddb8a1e43d94178-libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/releasever
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/d804bf01331824c1a148301bc5102dd7276e5136-libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/changed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/d804bf01331824c1a148301bc5102dd7276e5136-libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/d804bf01331824c1a148301bc5102dd7276e5136-libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/d804bf01331824c1a148301bc5102dd7276e5136-libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/command_line
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/d804bf01331824c1a148301bc5102dd7276e5136-libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/d804bf01331824c1a148301bc5102dd7276e5136-libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/from_repo_revision
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/d804bf01331824c1a148301bc5102dd7276e5136-libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/d804bf01331824c1a148301bc5102dd7276e5136-libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/d804bf01331824c1a148301bc5102dd7276e5136-libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/d804bf01331824c1a148301bc5102dd7276e5136-libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-11.el6-x86_64/releasever
```

EDIT: locate g++
OUTPUT:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/g++
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/x86_64-redhat-linux-g++
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/share/man/man1/g++.1.gz
/usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/x86_64-redhat-linux-g++
/usr/lib64/libconfig++.so.8
/usr/lib64/libconfig++.so.8.0.0
/usr/share/man/man1/g++.1.gz
```

Comment: devtoolset layers on top of your system rather than replacing the compiler, so be sure you're doing something like this to activate it: `scl enable devtoolset-2 'bash'`.  Also, be sure you don't have any object files or static libraries lying around from a previous compile

Comment: @Peter Thanks for your comment. I ran scl enable devtoolset-2 'bash' but still I am getting the same error. How do I find out object files or static libraries from previous compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so` is the older library which your application is trying to link against... and the newer library is installed somewhere else, which is not on the search path — or if it is on the search path, it comes *after* the old library, which is why the linker attempts to link against the older one, and fails.

Try doing this:

```
$ g++ program.cpp -L/path/to/new/stdlib -lstdc++ -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/new/stdlib
```

where `/path/to/new/stdlib` is the location of the new library. You can also set this on the beginning of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

---

Or

You're using older version of `g++`, and trying to against the newer version of `libstdc++.so`. Locate `g++` and use it. Use all 4 combinations of `g++` and `libstdc++` (if there are two versions of each of them).

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do I find path to new library?

Comment: @StegVerner: See `/use/local/lib` or `usr/local/lib64`.  Just `locate libstdc++`.

Comment: I have edited to my question output of locate libstdc++. I dont know which one is new one now

Comment: Post the output of `which g++`  and `g++ --version`. Also, compile your code with `-V` option and post the messages.

Comment: which g++ gives: /usr/bin/g++. g++ --version gives: g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)

Comment: Ahh... which means your using older version of g++.. and it tries to use new version of `libstdc++`.

Comment: ok..can you please guide me as to how can I install g++ on Scientific Linux 6

Comment: Try `locate g++`... and see how many of them are there on your system.

Comment: I have added locate g++ output to question as it was long

Comment: Don't forget that `locate` works off a database which refreshes by default once per day.

Comment: Also post the output of `/usr/bin/g++ --version` and `/usr/bin/x86_64-redhat-linux-g++ --version`. :D

Comment: /usr/bin/g++ --version gives g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) and /usr/bin/x86_64-redhat-linux-g++ gives
x86_64-redhat-linux-g++: no input files

Comment: @StegVerner: please use `--version` with the second command. I'm asking you to post the versions of each `g++`. So you need to understand few things **yourself**; otherwise it'd be really difficult to help you.

Comment: Sorry my bad.  /usr/bin/x86_64-redhat-linux-g++ --version gives
x86_64-redhat-linux-g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)

Comment: @StegVerner: That means you don't have `g++ 4.8` installed on your system. Or your `locate` couldn't find it, maybe you need to `updatedb` (as `root` user) as well before `locate g++`.

Comment: I have updated the output of locate g++ after running updatedb in my question

Comment: As usual, I'd like to know the version of each `g++` . So please post them as well *(post the exactly command as well, with each output)*. Do these things yourself before I ask you. It is getting difficult that I'm asking the similar questions again and again.

Comment: Very sorry. The version of /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/g++ --version is the correct one: g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)

Comment: After this I did rm /usr/bin/g++ and ln -s /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++. Now my g++ version gives: g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15). But still I am getting the same error with netbeans

Comment: @StegVerner: Great. Use `/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/g++` to compile your code and link against the compatible `libstdc++`. Maybe you'd like to **prepend** (not *append*)  `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the `[..]/bin` and `[...]/lib` respectively, in your `.bashrc`  if you dont want to write `/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/g++` everytime on the terminal.

Comment: I did the following: export PATH="$TDBROOT/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin:$PATH"
export CLASSPATH=".:$JENAROOT/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/g++/lib/*.jar" and restarted netbeans but still I am getting the same error with netbeans

Comment: @StegVerner: I don't think `CLASSPATH` has anything to do with it. Maybe it is Java thingy? (I'm not sure).

Comment: I restored CLASSPATH=".:$JENAROOT/g++/lib/*.jar"  but still I am getting the same error I dont know why

Comment: @StegVerner: As I said the value of `CLASSPATH` has nothing to do with it. It is most like a Java thingy. You should leave it in peace when you're working with `g++` (and C++ language).

Comment: Hmmm...very true :)..my gcc --version and g++ --version are both 4.8.2, then I dont know why am I getting this error

Comment: Thanks a lot..it worked..i restarted netbeans once more and it started working...thanks a lot again.